# Titles appearing instead of author in text when using bibtex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texmaker

This seems to me to be weird. I can't find any references to anything similar happening, the nearest I find is when a [?] appears instead of the author when using BibTeX.

Six months ago, I compiled a thesis, it worked fine, the references appeared fine. On a new computer, a new install of TeXmaker (4.4.1). Now, instead of author/year appearing in the text, the title of the article being referenced appears.

I took some of the preamble from the text file to create a minimal working example of the problem. My tex file now consists of:

```
\documentclass[12pt, english, onehalfspacing, liststotoc, toctotoc, parskip,]{MastersDoctoralThesis}        
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true,bibencoding=ascii,dashed=false]{biblatex}
%\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}% http://ctan.org/pkg/appendices
\addbibresource{minimal.bib} % The filename of the bibliography
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
blah blah blah\citep{Nicholson1992}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

My bib file consists of:

```
Automatically generated by Mendeley Desktop 1.17.10
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.
BibTeX export options can be customized via Options -> BibTeX in Mendeley Desktop

@article{Nicholson1992,
author = {Nicholson, R L and Hammerschmidt, R},
doi = {10.1146/annurev.py.30.090192.002101},
issn = {0066-4286},
journal = {Annual Review of Phytopathology},
number = {1},
pages = {369--389},
publisher = {Annual Reviews, Palo Alto, USA},
title = {Phenolic Compounds and Their Role in Disease Resistance},
url = {http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.py.30.090192.002101},
volume = {30},
year = {1992}
}
```

If I run

```
pdflatex minimal.tex 
bibtex minimal
pdflatex minimal.tex 
pdflatex minimal.tex
```

I get no errors, only a warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: File 'minimal.bbl' created by wrong version.
```

Otherwise, it produces a pdf with the following in the text body:

blah blah blah(“Phenolic Compounds and Their Role in Disease Resistance”)

Where do I start looking for a solution for this?

Comment: Well the `Package biblatex Warning: File 'minimal.bbl' created by wrong version.` is crucial. That means that something is out of sync. Try updating your TeX distribution. Then delete all temporary files and try again. BTW: Would it be an option to use Biber?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Do you use TeX live or MikTeX?

Comment: I'm using Mint. I've updated repository's and Texlive is at the latest version as best I can tell.

Comment: Do you use TeX live from the repositories or [vanilla](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)? Can you check your `biblatex` version?

Comment: When I run bibtex minimal, I get Warning--Version mismatch: biblatex.bst=2.3, biblatex.sty=2.6. The only references to this I've come across involve biber, which I'm not using. I could have another attempt at using biber, but every time I've tried to use it in the past, it's been ... spectacularly frustrating.

Comment: Also, I've been deleting all aux, blg and bbl files before I run these. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: Well, this shows that there is a version mismatch between your `biblatex.bst` and the rest of `biblatex`. This really should not happen if the package is installed properly. I had a similar problem on MikTeX once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61595/discussion-between-moewe-and-ben).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by an outdated file in the working directory that masked the file of the package installed via the distribution. After deleting the spurious file everything works fine again.