# Bibtex produces a line where the author of the book should appear

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

it is the first time I write in this site, and it happens that when I compile the bibliography with Bibtex I get a strange result in some references. As you can see in the following picture, in the place where the author's name should appear, it simply displays a line.

[image: Result of the bibliography]

The output of the command seems to be correct, no warnings or errors:

```
Proceso iniciado: bibtex.exe "TAI_template"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 20.12)
The top-level auxiliary file: TAI_template.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst
Database file #1: IEEEabrv.bib
Database file #2: Ref_Act4_19_20.bib
-- IEEEtran.bst version 1.14 (2015/08/26) by Michael Shell.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
-- See the "IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf" manual for usage information.

Done.

El proceso terminó normalmente
```

But most puzzling of all is that basically the entries are the same, only the title changes, but reference number 54 is correct, while 55-58 are wrong.

This is ref. 54:

```
@Book{BrownleeML,
  author    = {Jason Brownlee},
  editor    = {Jason Brownlee},
  publisher = {Jason Brownlee},
  title     = {{Machine Learning Mastery with Python: Understand Your Data, Create Accurate Models and Work Projects End-to-end}},
  year      = {2016},
  edition   = {First},
  url       = {https://books.google.es/books?id=0t-NAQAACAAJ},
}
```

And this is ref. 55:

```
@Book{BrownleeDL,
  author    = {Jason Brownlee},
  editor    = {Jason Brownlee},
  publisher = {Jason Brownlee},
  title     = {{Deep Learning With Python. Develop Deep Learning Models on Theano and TensorFlow Using Keras}},
  year      = {2016},
  edition   = {First},
  url       = {https://machinelearningmastery.com/deep-learning-with-python/},
}
```

Could this be a bug? Or, maybe I'm doing something wrong? Nothing like this has ever happened to me. And the most similar question I could find didn't help me ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378279/titles-appearing-instead-of-author-in-text-when-using-bibtex)).
Can anyone have any ideas?

*If it helps, I am using Windows (Miktex), with TeXstudio as editor and Jabref as reference manager.*

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Some bibliography styles replace repeated author names with a horizontal line. See also: [Is it normal for BibTeX to replace similar author names with “------”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29381/134144)

Comment: Please confirm that you use the `IEEEtran` bibliography style.

Comment: "Could this be a bug?" Ah, this is like to resist shouting the "two bits"  after a "shave and a haircut", I had to say it: "It is not a bug, it is a feature".

Comment: Thank you very much, @leandriis, that's exactly the "problem" I had. I have followed the solution in the link you indicate and I have already solved it.

Comment: Yes, @Mico, I'm using IEEEtran style, I didn't know there was that "feature" of omitting the author when repeated.

Comment: As others have mentioned excessively already this is standard behaviour of the IEEEtran BibTeX style. It is, however, not quite clear whether the IEEE still want this behaviour (since it is not mentioned in recent reference guides and not observed in a number of recently published papers), I have emailed the `IEEEtran` author about this, but he was not aware of a change in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior isn't related to Windows, MikTeX, TeXstudio, or Jabref, but is controlled by the `(bib)style` set by whatever package you are using for your bibliography. So your `.tex` file (or a MWE) would be more useful to help solve your specific issue.

If you are using `biblatex`, simply add the option `dashed=false` to change this behavior.

Comment: In this case I am using Bibtex, and the solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29385/239904) has helped me (thanks to @leandris for pointing out the thread).
Thanks anyway for your help.